# Vuetify - call method when user finished selecting items in v-autocomplete with multiple selection?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to call a method when a user is finished selecting items in a `v-autocomplete` with multiple selection. I can't bind to the `@input` or `@change` events because they're called after each selection, and I need to call this method after the full batch of selections.

Is there an event to bind to when the dropdown menu closes?

Or is there a way of adding actions at the bottom of the dropdown menu, similar to the style of [this date picker menu](https://codepen.io/miranda-rose/pen/LYPxbqB)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track it using `@blur` event.

```html
<v-autocomplete @blur="method"></v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! Wish it was in their documentation.